# Will an SSD lose power while a computer is off, but still plugged in?

Tags: ssd, packet-loss

I have been reading into SSD data loss when there is no flow of power, and what I have read is somewhat unclear.

From what I know an SSD begins losing data after 7 days without supplied power. Will this occur if it is connected to a PC that is plugged in, but hasn't been turned on in a week?

Comment: No, that's not how it works.

Comment: So it needs to be completely removed from a power source?

Comment: You might wish to quote your source. I see 1 year (power off) at 30 degrees C.  I saw a couple such posts Lots of desktop computers come with SSD drives now.

Comment: Manufacturers recommend not left it **on a shelf** for more than one year or you *might* experience data loss.  What you think you know it ain't so.

Comment: I did not do any in depth study, I was merely responding to the 7 day comment in the original post. I would also expect much more than a year. I just have never tested data storage.

Comment: The SSD's power state is controlled by the system mainboard, not the mains power. Also, what you have "heard" about SSDs and data loss is entirely and completely false. Either you misheard, or you're misinformed.

Answer (score 2):

Solid State Disks, and flash memory in general, will hold their data for years - decades even - without power.  There is nothing to fear in storing flash drives, SSDs, or any flash media for many years unpowered.

I see the [article](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/205382-ssds-can-lose-data-in-as-little-as-7-days-without-power) I believe you are referring to and I find it... questionable.  First off its old.  Secondly, its talking about enterprise drives and storing drives in high temperatures.  Neither of which you are likely using or doing.  Also, the data is anecdotal, at best.